# edit android app from browser

Tags: android, database, textview

I'm a newbie, and i want to know if there's anyway to add/edit text to show on a textview from a Compuer brower.

What i would like to do is everyday write an Article to show to the user. is that possible?
This is my XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cdiscount"
/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/auchan"
 />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon"
  />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gb" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rdc" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
 />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
 />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
 />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've edited the xml.
so what i want to do is, when i click a button, it takes me to a textview. and i want full access of this textview.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you want to do?  Do you want to update your website from computer and then have that reflected in the app?

Comment: I'm guessing what you need is a mobile website.  This can be built using jQuery mobile for example.  As the owner of the mobile site you could have an edit page that only you could access. General users would just see that latest article you published.  Actually you would probably do this in Wordpress using a mobile friendly theme.

Comment: When you clicked a button where?

Comment: See my updated answer below.  One step at a time.  I think you need to manage an EditText and a TextView to get the first part done.  Second part might be to store the article on Google Docs or in SharedPreferences on the device depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. Browser doesn't know how to communicate with device (how to use adb). You need a web service that will feed your application with data (articles or whatever). Application needs to implement GCM to be aware of a new available article. Http communication, and data parsing.

Comment: Well lets see what the user is trying to do.

Comment: I'm guessing its a mobile website.

Comment: Ok.  Here is the deal. You need an EditText and a TextEdit to do this. And like the other comments if there is more than one user for the app you need to save off on server side, but it its just notes to self you can store locally.

Comment: Another button to save off the edit.  Once its saved off hide the EditText and replace the contents in the TextView with what is now in the EditText.  I see what you are trying to do now.

Answer (score 0):

Your app hat to parse/read data from your server every time it launches, for example an json-file produced by php.
[How to read json in android](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) (in this case: twitter-api) + [How to make your own json(-api)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5pXxS0y4bg)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my answer.  I think this is what you need.

A combination of an EditText myChangesToArticle;
                    TextView myArticle;

set visibility to GONE on myChangesToArticle.

When user clicks on button.  Change visibility to VISIBLE from GONE.

Make edit or enter new article.  Press Save button.

myArticle.setText(myChangesToArticle.getText());
myChangesToArticle.setVisibility(View.GONE);

To make this globally visibile you could just update a remote spreadsheet on google docs or whatever when you save off.  And retrieve from there as well using HttpClient.

Comment: well this is not what i'm lokking for.

Comment: I think what you need to do is have a EditText in another activity. When you click on that Activity it will go to that activity and you can enter the values over there. Right?

Comment: You could also put he EditText in another activity and do a startActivityForResult().